# How to grep this line "12/15-12:24:51 <1692> @@ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 691 0"

Tags: regex, perl

I've a file called test.txt

```
12/15-12:24:51 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  691    0
12/15-12:24:51 <1692> END SESSION SUMMARY
12/15-12:24:55 <1692> INFO: SESSION SUMMARY
12/15-12:24:55 <1692>       +    -   ch    G    B    C    L    S    T    X    Y    -
12/15-12:24:55 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  692    0
12/15-12:24:55 <1692> END SESSION SUMMARY
12/15-12:24:59 <1692> INFO: SESSION SUMMARY
12/15-12:24:59 <1692>       +    -   ch    G    B    C    L    S    T    X    Y    -
12/15-12:24:59 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  692    0
12/15-12:24:59 <1692> END SESSION SUMMARY
12/15-12:25:03 <1692> INFO: SESSION SUMMARY
12/15-12:25:03 <1692>       +    -   ch    G    B    C    L    S    T    X    Y    -
12/15-12:25:03 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  692    0
12/15-12:25:03 <1692> END SESSION SUMMARY
12/15-12:25:07 <1692> INFO: SESSION SUMMARY
12/15-12:25:07 <1692>       +    -   ch    G    B    C    L    S    T    X    Y    -
12/15-12:25:07 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  692    0
12/15-12:25:07 <1692> END SESSION SUMMARY
```

and need output as

```
12/15-12:24:51 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  691    0
12/15-12:24:55 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  692    0
12/15-12:24:59 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  692    0
12/15-12:25:03 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  692    0
12/15-12:25:07 <1692> @@    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  692    0
```

Tried following way but couldn't get

```
cat test.txt | perl -e '$str = do { local $/; <> }; while ($str =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)?\s.*/) { print "$1:$2:$3:$4\n"}'
```

Comment: Looks like you just want to grep for `@@`.

Answer (score 4):

Your one-liner has some mistakes. I will go through them, then show you a solution.

```
cat test.txt |
```

You don't need to cat into a pipe, just use the file name as argument when using diamond operator `<>`.

```
perl -e '$str = do { local $/; <> };
```

This slurps the entire file into a single string. This is not useful in your case. This is only useful if you are expecting matches that include newlines.

```
while ($str =~ /(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)?\s.*/) {
```

This part will only run once, because you did not use the `/g` modifier. This is especially bad since you are not running in line-by-line mode, because you slurped the file.

The regex will try to match one of the time stamps, I assume, e.g. `12:25:07`. Why you would want to do that is beyond me, since each line in your input has such a time stamp, rendering the whole operation useless. You want to try to match something that is unique for the lines you do want.

```
print "$1:$2:$3:$4\n"}'
```

This part prints 4 capture groups, and you only have 3 (2 fixed and 1 optional). It will not print the entire line.

What you want is something simplistic like this:

```
perl -ne'print if /\@\@/' test.txt
```

Which will go through the file line-by-line, check each line for `@@` and print the lines found.

Or if you are using *nix, just `grep '@@' test.txt`